# Relayjs performance really bad, setVariables

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay, react-router-relay

Does anyone know what causes these huge blocking functions in Relay when making requests? I have a search box that calls `setVariables` and it's immensely noticeable.

[image]

It's much better in production. Still curious though

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code?